# drawUnderTabBar property is not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation and drawUnderTabBar property does not show my screen background behind the tabs. I have tried placing the prop in navigatorStyle, appStyle, and tabsStyle to no effect